# Complex integral of a function.

Tags: complex-analysis

straight forward: $f(z)=|z|$

Integrate the complex function:

1. Direct way from 1 to -1 on the X-axis
2. same from 1 to -1 but this time using the upper half of the circle.
3. Can the function be holomorphic?

My problem is i don't have much experience with integrals of complex numbers.
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(z)=|z|$.  We analyze the integral of $f$ from $(1,0)$ to $(-1,0)$ along two different contours.

For the first integral, let $z=x$, so that $dz=dx$, $|z|=|x|$, and where $x$ begins at $1$ and ends at $-1$.  Therefore, we have

$$\int_{1}^{-1} |x|\,dx=-2\int_0^1x\,dx=-1$$

For the second integral, let $z=e^{i\theta}$, so that $dz=ie^{i\theta}$, $|z|=1$, and where $\theta$ begins at $0$ and ends at $\pi$.  Therefore, we have

$$\int_0^{\pi}ie^{i\theta}d\theta=-2$$

If $f$ were holomorphic in the plane, then $\oint_C f(z)\,dz =0$ for all sufficiently smooth, closed contours $C$.  Therefore, since we have shown that this does not hold for $f(z)=|z|$, then $f$ is not holomorphic.